# How can I highlight the invisible Unicode character &# 65279; in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes, I (in release) find this character. So, how can I highlight it in Visual Studio Code?

PS: I know about UTF-8 without a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), but to fix it, I need to open a page with the code in [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) and change encoding. And I want to see this Unicode character in Visual Studio Code somehow highlighted, so I can see it (and delete it later).

Comment: Does setting   "editor.renderControlCharacters": true,  help?

Comment: unfortunately doesn't help it: 
[html](http://joxi.ru/E2pqj0BuB13DLA)
[index](http://joxi.ru/a2XXq6KUyd6zM2)
[footer](http://joxi.ru/8AnqJMpuqVOaM2)

Comment: 65279 (decimal) = 0xFEFF (hexadecimal)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[How it works](http://joxi.ru/v29pxEXUGWxl5m)

1. I add extension [Gremlins](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nhoizey.gremlins)
2. and in *C:\Users\tomnolane.vscode\extensions\nhoizey.gremlins-0.6.2\extension.js*, add this code:

   ```
    const gremlins = [
      {
       ...
      },
      {
        char: 'feff',
        regex: /\ufeff+/g,
        width: 0,
        message: 'Zero Width No-Break Space',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,127,80,.5)',
        overviewRulerColor: 'rgba(255,127,80,1)',
      },
      {
        char: '2060',
        regex: /\u2060+/g,
        width: 0,
        message: 'Word Joiner',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,127,80,.5)',
        overviewRulerColor: 'rgba(255,127,80,1)',
      },
      {
        char: 'fffe',
        regex: /\ufffe+/g,
        width: 0,
        message: 'Not a Character',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,127,80,.5)',
        overviewRulerColor: 'rgba(255,127,80,1)',
      },
    ]
   ```
3. then, reload Visual Studio Code and it works!

Comment: Add Gremlins and reload Visual Studio Code, maybe the extension has already upgraded its code :D

Answer (score 2):

With the new setting: `Editor > Unicode Highlight: Invisible Characters` set to `true` or `deriveFromWorkspaceTrust`.

In file [settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)

```json
"editor.unicodeHighlight.invisibleCharacters": true,
```

the Unicode character `U+200B` (zero-width space character) will be highlighted.

See more at [How can I find Unicode characters that are not UTF-8 in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64093078/how-can-i-find-unicode-characters-that-are-not-utf-8-in-visual-studio-code/70164173#70164173).

Comment: U+FEFF is not 'zero-width space'. U+FEFF is [ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/66). U+200B is [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9).