# How can I find Unicode characters that are not UTF-8 in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have Unicode characters that I can't see that are not UTF-8, and I need to spot them.

I used the extension [Highlight Bad Chars (Kevin Wenger)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wengerk.highlight-bad-chars), but it's not sufficient. In particular, I don't know which these characters are and I don't want to have to define them in advance.

How can I do this with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Note: there are instances where you do not want to spot some Unicode non-utf8 characters: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140960

Comment: Related (the same underlying cause for the problem): *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/)*

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Find [^\x00-\x7f] and check *Use Regular Expression*.

It is taken from *[Finding Those Pesky Unicode Characters in Visual Studio](https://weblogs.asp.net/kon/finding-those-pesky-unicode-characters-in-visual-studio)*.

Answer (score 39):

You can try the [Gremlins](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nhoizey.gremlins) extension which I found better than `Highlight Bad Chars (Kevin Wenger)` (at least, Gremlins worked out of the box; I couldn't get Highlight Bad Chars to highlight anything).

Comment: It's open source: https://github.com/nhoizey/vscode-gremlins

Comment: Highlight Bad Chars was updated on 11/2/2021, so part of the answer no longer holds true.

Comment: IMO, Gremlins is a very targeted and well-done plugin.

Comment: very cool plugin, thanks for the headsup

Answer (score 9):

In Stable Build v1.63 there is a new method for highlighting various Unicode characters that might otherwise be difficult to spot in your code.  These are the new settings:

[image: New Unicode settings]

You can use these `colorCustomizations` to change the default orange borders:

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "editorUnicodeHighlight.border": "#00ff37",
    "editorUnicodeHighlight.background": "#f00",        // will be in vscode v1.66

    // "minimap.unicodeHighlight": "#ff0000",           // removed in v1.64
    // "editorOverviewRuler.unicodeForeground": "#ff0000"    // removed in v1.64
}
```

> Apparently, indicators for these Unicode warnings will not be shown in the minimap or overview ruler as of v1.64, see [Consider removing the Unicode highlight scroll bar decoration](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141152)

Here is how a Unicode [zero-width space](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9) (U+200B) appears with these settings:

[image: Unicode zero-width space in Visual Studio Code]

The zero-width character is an *invisible Unicode character* controlled by the `Unicode Highlight: Invisible Characters` setting above.

---

From [v1.63 release notes: Unicode highlighting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#unicode-highlighting)

> Read [this article](https://certitude.consulting/blog/en/invisible-backdoor/) or [this article](https://www.trojansource.codes/) for how invisible or confusable
> Unicode characters can be used in Unicode spoofing attacks.
>
> Note that this feature does not detect all possible Unicode spoofing
> attacks, as this depends on your font and locale settings. Also, the
> detection of ambiguous characters is done heuristically. To be on the
> safe side, the restricted mode of the workspace trust should be used
> to review source code, as all non-ASCII characters are highlighted in
> untrusted workspaces.
>
> The settings `editor.unicodeHighlight.invisibleCharacters`,
> `editor.unicodeHighlight.ambiguousCharacters` or
> `editor.unicodeHighlight.nonBasicASCII` can be set to false to disable
> the corresponding feature.
>
> Individual characters can be excluded from being highlighted and
> characters in comments or text and markdown documents are not
> highlighted by default.