# C# calling a post method in other API getting 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I am calling a post method from one API to other in C# and getting a 404 Not Found error. When i look at the request message the request Uri looks good but Absolute Uri and Absolute path has some special characters inserted

- My request Uri - https://services.abc.com:1232/something/v1/abc/add
- My Absolute Uri - https://services.abc.com:1232/something/v1/%E2%80%8Babc%E2%80%8B/add

This is how im calling the end point

```
var baseUrl = https://services.abc.com:1232/something;     
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{baseUrl}/v1/​abc/add");
requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%E2%80%8B` encodes (for example according to [this site](https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+200B)) [Zero-width space (U+200B)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) space character which is not shown by Visual Studio (I assume you use it). Try deleting `/abc/` part and retyping it manually (or try copying this - `$"{baseUrl}/v1/abc/add"`), it seems that you have managed to copy-paste the character from somewhere.

Also answer to [Zero Width Space character in string literals: Detect and/or prevent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32013346/2501279) can be useful.